# array change key name with own words

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 6
)
```

Can i change my key with my own words in php. Please suggest

//Expecting like this

```
Array
(
    [h] => 3
    [c] => 5
    [s] => 7
    [e] => 8
    [r] => 4
    [t] => 6
)
```

Comment: Did did you create the array?

Comment: `array_combine(['h','c','s','e','r','t'],[3,5,7,8,4,6])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this

```
$myarr = array(3,5,7,8,4,6);
$newkeys = array('h','c','s','e','r','t');
$c=array_combine($newkeys ,$myarr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. Your syntaxes are wrong. you can use arrays like this.

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);

// as of PHP 5.4
$array = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
```

For more clarification check the [official php Maual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could   use an assign  and an unset   this way

```
$your_array[$your_newkey] = $your_array[$your_oldkey];
unset($your_array[$your_oldkey]);
```